# How to properly pass Array to Class

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, class, flash-cs5

Hi I try pass my Arry to Class. I try to pass it and it look like this:

Frame 32 earlier are some animations.

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import Wyjazd;

stop();

ofertaBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wyskok);
function wyskok(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var vektor:Array = new Array(I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X,XI,XII);
    var menu:Wyjazd = new Wyjazd(vektor);
}
```

Class

```
    package 
{
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.motion.easing.*;
    import flash.filters.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Wyjazd extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Wyjazd(ar:Array)
        {
            var xX = ar.x;
            var time:Number = 2;
            var offset:Number = 0;
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                var tween:Tween = new Tween(ar[i],"x",Sine.easeOut,ar[i].x,266.65 + offset,time,true);
                ar[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,podswietlenie);
                ar[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,zgaszenie);

                time +=  0.2;
                offset +=  15.25;
            }
            function zgaszenie(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                ar[i].filters = [];
            }
            function podswietlenie(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                var pods:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter  ;
                pods.inner = false;
                pods.color = 0x000000;
                pods.knockout = false;
                ar[i].filters = [pods];
            }
            /*var targetLabel:String;
            ar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, podswietlenie);
            ar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, zgaszenie);

            ar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,przejscie);
            function przejscie(e:MouseEvent)
            {
            targetLabel= e.currentTarget.name;
            tween = new Tween(ar,"x",Sine.easeOut,ar.x,xX,time,true);
            trace(targetLabel);
            }*/

        }

    }
}
```

But I still gets  Error #1063. It say that I pass no argument. How pass it properly? So Could you help me?

UPDATE #1:
I use try use trace. Frame code isn't chance but Class look like this.

```
package 
{
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.motion.easing.*;
    import flash.filters.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Wyjazd extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Wyjazd(ar:Array)
        {
            trace(ar.length);
            //reast is commented

        }

    }
}
```

But still, I got Error #1063, we must go deeper. Then I change frame code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
stop();
ofertaBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wyskok);
function wyskok(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var vektor:Array = [I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X,XI,XII];
    trace(vektor.lenght);
    //var menu:Wyjazd = new Wyjazd(vektor);
}
```

Now I got Error #1007 Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. at site_fla::MainTimeline/wyskok()

Comment: Your last update has an error.  `var vektor:Array = new Array[I,II...];` should be `var vektor:Array = [I,II...];` Using the `[]` form declares a new array, you don't need to say so.

Comment: Yea I know that it's correct now.

Comment: Also: `trace(vektor.lenght);` you have misspelled length.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you meant to quote each of the values in the array:

```
new Array('I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII');
```

Comment: No beacuse those are objects, and this is array of objects.

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #1063: not match argument list in Wyjazd(). Expect 1, Got 0.

Comment: You sure you copied the code over *exactly*? Could be a typo.

Comment: @Dudi test this comment

Answer (score 0):

To narrow it down, I would suggest commenting out your Wyjazd function code and replacing it with a trace statement such as trace(ar.length);

See if you can run that and if it traces out the array length.  If it can, then the problem is not the passing of the array to the function.

I was able to test this and it worked for me when I created this, so that's why I suggest the above.

If it does still throw the same error, then can you supply me with a little more information?

1. Are you using Flash Professional?
2. Are you calling var vektor from frame 1 in the actions tab?
3. Are you calling the Wyjazd class from your main document any other way (such as adding the class to the .fla properties?

Comment: I am calling var vektor from action tab and in frame 32 earlier ther are some animations. I am calling class form frame actions and I add it  in Document Class.

Comment: Did you try commenting out your main function body and replacing it with a trace statement of ar.length?

Comment: Yes, yes all is in my question update because it's a lot of new code.

Comment: And, yes I use Professional CS5.5

Comment: I use trace(vektor.lenght) is undefined.

Comment: "length" is misspelled. You want trace(vektor.length)  If that still throws an error, then I would take a look at your objects.  You might want to throw in String objects into the array and try to trace that out and see if it works.  If it does work when you pass Strings or numbers then its more than likely a problem with your objects.  Trace trace trace!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vektor:Array = [I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX,X,XI,XII];
```

Also, I think this line is not correct:

```
var xX = ar.x;
```

.. and btw, you could change this too

```
// for (var i:Number = 0; i < 12; i++)
for (var i:int = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
```

Comment: var xX was from earlier version I totaly forgot about it. Thanks for ar.lenght and "[]" but still not working Error #1063

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a parameter for a symbol that is instanciate from the IDE, check this similar question and answer : [AS3 not accepting constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149678/as3-not-accepting-constructor/2149826#2149826)

You have to try to initialize your class differentely, but it really depends on your usage

for example :

```
public class Wyjazd extends MovieClip
{

    public function Wyjazd(ar:Array=null) // use a default parameter
    {
        if (ar!=null) init(ar) // call your init function

    }
    public function init(ar:Array):void {
        var xX = ar.x;
        var time:Number = 2;
        var offset:Number = 0;
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            var tween:Tween = new Tween(ar[i],"x",Sine.easeOut,ar[i].x,266.65 + offset,time,true);
            ar[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,podswietlenie);
            ar[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,zgaszenie);

            time +=  0.2;
            offset +=  15.25;
        }
        function zgaszenie(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            ar[i].filters = [];
        }
        function podswietlenie(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            var pods:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter  ;
            pods.inner = false;
            pods.color = 0x000000;
            pods.knockout = false;
            ar[i].filters = [pods];
        }
        /*var targetLabel:String;
        ar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, podswietlenie);
        ar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, zgaszenie);

        ar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,przejscie);
        function przejscie(e:MouseEvent)
        {
        targetLabel= e.currentTarget.name;
        tween = new Tween(ar,"x",Sine.easeOut,ar.x,xX,time,true);
        trace(targetLabel);
        }*/
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So as I'm thinking good as I think, function Wyjazd is a constructor and it doesn't have information about object in stage attached by Flash IDE but it can pass it to another function?

Comment: Sorry Dudi i have not understand.

Comment: Function Wyjazd is a constrictor of class with same name, with attached symbols and there I can't use constructor arguements in that function. But I can pass whole array to another function and do with it as regular function do. I hope that was more clearly.

Comment: But now when it works, my EventListeners wont works. Error #1010  A term is undefined and has no properties. at MethodInfo-200()

Comment: @Dudi, Yes you can do that, you have an example above. You just have to find when called the init function.

Comment: hmm.. ok but one more question, I add ar[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,podswietlenie);
    ar[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,zgaszenie); 
At for but I got Error #1010 A term is undefined and has no properties. at MethodInfo-202()